# Only allow order for specific post codes in a specific country?

Tags: orders

I want to make orders possible for only a list of post codes in a specific country. Is is possible?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I'm aware of is to doesn't provide a shipping method available.

Use the Table rates shipping method and specify the country and its allowed post-codes

When in the checkout the user write an "invalid" combination of country/post codes a default message "No shipping method is available" comes up.

Comment: While this approach works and uses only built-in features it could be frustrating for the customer who has completed a good portion of the cart/checkout process.

Comment: Sure it is. But unless you register yourself and add also the shipping address Magento have no way to know where your order will be shipped. The suggestion of philwinkle can helps thing up.

Answer (score 1):

I like the method proposed by @giuseppe - I would just caution you to make the customer aware of the limited shipping before they get too excited to begin shopping.

Usually this can be done by prompting people (via modal, other means) to see if you ship to their region. I would highly suggest calling attention to the shipping estimator widget on the cart as a means to help customers who aren't sure if you can deliver to them.