# Limit Orders to a specific country

Tags: orders, shipping, countries

I have changed the Allowed Countries within Magento to only show United Kingdom, however, we only want to accept orders for the UK Mainland, which excludes Ireland (the UK includes Scotland, Northern Ireland, England and Wales).

I've tried researching this but I cannot find anything to change this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

A common solution is shipping restriction by postcode. Here is another question on the topic: [Only allow order for specific post codes in a specific country?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25676/only-allow-order-for-specific-post-codes-in-a-specific-country?rq=1)

Basically one option is to use the table rates shipping method and do not provide any shipping rate for restricted areas. Another option is to use one of the commercial extensions for shipping restriction.

Or you write your own module with an observer for `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling` and `..._saveShipping` where you check the address and redirect back with an error if it is not allowed. You have to observe both events even if you only want to check the shipping address, because in "saveBilling" the option "use for shipping" might have been selected.

Comment: Unfortunately we already use an extension for shipping called "Shipping Rules" by MageKart, so I'm not sure how possible this will be, sorry, I should have stated this in my question.

Comment: Then use it? From their feature list: "Create shipping restrictions based on Magento shipping weight, order total, address line, zip code, region, etc."

Comment: We are using it, but only to increase the price for certain post codes. I can see no way in which to disable post codes entirely.

Comment: I don't know the extension so I cannot help you with it, but from what they advertise, it should be possible.